# Quantum physics and object location

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements

If I understand correctly, according to quantum physics, subatomic particles can "leap" from one location to another (for example, from a location on earth to a location on the "other side" of the universe). Is this property unique to subatomic particles or is it possible (no matter how highly improbable) for objects of any size to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think of it as leaping. An object's location is not well-defined unless and until a measurement of its position has been made.

In [Classical Mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_mechanics), the motion of a particle is given by its position and its momentum. In [Quantum Mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics), the fundamental "thing" that controls a particle's motion is its [wave function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefunction), and wave functions are *mucho* bizarre.

Basically, a particle's wave function evolves in time according to [Schrödinger's Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_equation) and based on its initial wave function (at time $t=0$). But the physically relevant quantity for a particle is its wave function *squared*, which is its probability distribution.

In other words, the wave function squared gives you the likelihood of a particle being found at a given location when you take a measurement of its position. So, in principal, a particle could be found anywhere since (broadly speaking) a particle's wave function dies off [exponentially](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay) in space (but never goes to exactly zero).

There are quite a lot of subtleties I'm leaving out, but it is also worth noting that measuring a particle's position gives you *infinite uncertainty* in its momentum (by the [uncertainty principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle)) which means that if you wait a short time and make another measurement of the particle's position it will be roughly as likely to be across the universe as in your backyard.

This holds true *in principle* for classical objects, but you can think of classical objects as having measurements taken of them almost continuously. That means that they don't have time to evolve away from their current position in a quantum mechanical way.

Comment: By "measurement of position" do you mean by a (human) observer or any kind of interaction with other particles?

Comment: If I knew the answer to that, I would be a famous man. A "measurement" is any interaction with the system that would cause information about the state of the system to be deducible from the result of the interaction. Do "measurements" require "observers" (i.e. people)? No. What is the nature of an interaction which measures position or momentum or energy? I don't know. That is a very tough question. In QM parlance, a measurement might be called an "inner product between the initial ket and the final bra," but that is highly unenlightening. Certainly, not all interactions "measure" position.

Comment: Somebody should model measurement as a physical process. That would help answer the question.

Comment: There is no mind-dependence involved. Nobody has to look at the experiment/instruments.